# Increase zooming scale at higher scales?

Tags: usability, zooming

as i zoom out more the changes are less meaningful
1x to 2x is a lot more different then 31x to 32x
google chrome seems to deal with this by changing the scale at which it zooms

```
100%
125%
150%
175%
200%
250%
300%
400%
500%
```

etc
how can i curve my scales (1-32 or any range i guess) thusly?
this only happens when i scroll with mouse from int to int... pinch works fine

Comment: I think we're missing some context...what are we zooming? A web page? A map?

Comment: i am using this for a game board

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that zooming should (approximately) follow a geometric progression.  For example, a coarse-grained scale would be:

25% -> 50% -> 100% -> 200% -> 400% (zoom ratio of 2)

while a finer-grained scale might be:

25% -> 35% -> 50% -> 70% -> 100% -> 140% -> 200% -> 280% -> 400% (zoom ratio of roughly 1.4)

Comment: neither of those are curved and both have the problem described in my post of 'slowing down' when you get further out

Comment: @rakkarage they are both non-linear (curved). And I don't see a comment about slowing down in your OP. What do you mean by that?

Comment: "as i zoom out more the changes are less meaningful" was what i meant by slower... and sorry i did not comprehend the numbers.... or math in general :) i get it now thanks